# In Java, what collection is the most performant for a network of data?

Tags: java, performance, collections, neural-network

I have a network of "entities" (Objects), each containing information as to what the "next"(following) entities are, which can be anything between none and a lot. Also, the "next" entities contain information to their "next entities" (which can be a completely new one or the previous one, that just linked to it).

So A knows where B an C is, B knows where A, D and E ist and so on. Notice the both-way direction of A and B. There is no limit as to the number or direction of connections.

What would be the best (most performant) collection to simulate such a network if I have to search through the entities very often (many thousands of times)? What would be the best collection if I were searching for strings instead of objects? Does it make a difference? Would any other type of entity be faster?

Thanks everyone!

Edit: What I'm trying to do is to save a huge number of "memories" (historical events in a simulation) in a network/graph, then search for a certain memory and follow the connections to it's neighbours and the neighbours of the neighbours and so on, looking for "combinations" of memories that fit my search pattern. For example I'm verifying if the entities "A, B, C and again A" exist in this order.

Comment: In terms of graph theory, what sort of operations do you wish to perform on your graph? (find path between 2 nodes? connected components? if 2 nodes are connected.. etc)

Comment: Well...quite different actions, actually. I want to be able to search for a certain node (using it's name/key), then go to it's immediate neighbors ("nextEntity") and the neighbors of its neighbors. While I'm doing this I have to check the "distances" between nodes, which will most likely be an attribute attached to the list of "neighbors" that each node has. Ad I also want to compare attributes of nodes. The problem is, it's not a "tree" that eventually ends, since the relationship between nodes allows circles - node A and B can be connected both ways, there is no parent-child relationship.

Comment: Try Map<Node, List<Node>> to map a node to its children. Alternatively you can have Node with a List<Node> children inside the Node class. You can then do all sorts of operations on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me as if you have a "graph"-type problem.  Perhaps you could use a neo4j (http://neo4j.org/) as a way to represent your relationships, and then use its API to do your searches?

Comment: Wow, this looks very promising. I'll definitely take a closer look at this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've been trying out Neo4J for the past 2 days and it seemed very promising, but the moment I simulated creating 1000 nodes I realized how slow this process was... it took a couple of seconds. Am I doing something wrong or is it really that way?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather vague as it stands. If you can somehow define a "key" for your search terms, you could use a `HashMap` data structure (in `java.util`) as a very fast lookup table.

The worst-case scenario is where you have to use depth first search (DFS) or breadth first search (BFS) to search through the entire network (the technical term is "graph").

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to save a huge number of "memories" (historical events in a simulation) in a network/graph, then search for a certain memory and follow the connections to it's neighbours and the neighbours of the neighbours and so on, looking for "combinations" of memories that fit my search pattern. For example I'm verifying if the entities "A, B, C and again A" exist in this order.

Comment: "Breadth first" would imply that I have some sort of tree collection, but I have no "parent-child" relationships. Circles are possible.

Comment: No, you can do BFS on any type of graph, not only on trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Map<Entity, List<Entity>>
```

?

The map stores the entity itself plus a list of all successors (next and/or previous). Accessing the maps values using the key is always O(1) which means the element is accessed in a constant amount of time (it is not dependent on how many elements are stored in the map)

If you have the constraint that the entities should be placed in a special order (position) this approach will certainly not work.

Comment: But doesn't this mean I have each entity stored multiple times (Once in the map and then multiple times in different Lists)?

Comment: You will only store the reference to the object (so memory on the stack is allocated). The object itself is only stored one time on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to search for entities itself? If so, as a general solution you can create a HashMap where keys a class that corresponds to your search criteria. Entities will be a values.

If you would add more information about searching it would be possible to propose more adequate solutions.

Ex1: entities have numeric attributes and search criteria is when attribute > particular threshold - RBTReeMap would be solution.

Ex2: you are searching sequences of entities - Graph search algorithms may be considered.

Ex3: Your entities structure is very similar to FSA (Finite State Automatons). In this case - search here is done over input language (not entities itself). Solutions are minimization of automaton and making it deterministic.

Comment: I'm searching for only one entity, and then checking the sequence of entities starting from that one. Graph search algorithms sound interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on what an Entity is, and define it a class for that. If you need to find an Entity, just register it in a map on creation.

Something like this:

```
public class Entity {
    static Map<String, Entity> map = new HashMap<String, Entity>();

    String id;
    Set<Entity> nextEntities = new HashSet<Entity>();
    Set<Entity> prevEntities = new HashSet<Entity>();

    public Entity (String id) {
        this.id = id;
        map.put(id, this);
    }

    public static forId(String id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't have any "starting position", I first need to search for an entity to start from every time.  And that's where the algorithm has to move fast. So I'm looking for Object "xyz" and then check its neighbours and the neighbours of it's neighbours etc.

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty good, I'll give it a go. Is "Map" faster than the "HashMap" tskuzzy proposed?

Comment: `Map` is just an Interface which is implemented by `HashMap`. But Bohemian forgot to initialize `map`: `static Map<String, Entity> map = new HashMap<String, Entity>();`

Comment: @hage I didn't "forget" to initialize it. I deliberately left it out, just like I left out getters and setters. I'm communicating the class design here - I included only the code the is directly relevant to the answer. But if it's a big deal, then fine - I've updated the answer

Comment: @Bohemian It's no big deal.. I just wanted to clarify, because you had initialized `nextEntities` and `prevEntities`.

Comment: Thanks, although the static construct is not the best for my problem, since I'm going to have multiple maps. But I got the point, I placed my map in an extra class that controls Entity creation etc. I can't make a picture of Maps vs Sets in my mind though, maps are faster?

Comment: @Cos HashMaps and HashSets have the same look-up speed - they both use a hash table internally. It has order o(log n) speed.